# xpath innertext without any child node contents

Tags: xpath, xhtml

I have some HTML like this (which I cannot change):

```
<div>
    <p class="name">
        <span>Employee Name: </span>
        John Smith
    </p>
</div>
```

And I'd like to use xpath to extract out just the "John Smith" part..

I have been trying to use this code:

```
//div//p[@class='name']//text()
```

However, it doesn't work.

What is the best way to achieve what I'm after?

Many thanks.

Comment: I almost ask this kind of question. Got here from so.com suggestion when I wrote my question title. Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it.

**Change your XPath to: `//div//p[@class='name']/text()`**

When you use `//text()`, it selects all of the descendant `text()` nodes, which includes the "Employee Name: " text node that is a child of the `<span>`.

It is best to avoid the `//` when possible, as it makes your expressions less efficient and more prone to those sort of issues.

Comment: for future readers, note that /text() return a list, so each fragment divided by tag (hence not belonging to an inner tag) will be an element of such list. Making an analogy with split() the return is like "use any inner tag as separator", so the return are just the fragments.